# "Document in ADF" on Canon MX340

Tags: printer, canon-pixma

I have a Canon MX340 multifunction printer.  Recently, it keeps saying "Document in ADF" when I turn on the printer.   I've tried clearing this multiple times, but as soon as the feeder wheels stop turning, in an attempt to clear the document feeder, it just pops up the same error again.     This is particularly annoying, as it blocks all functions on the device - I cannot print, even though printing has no interaction with the document feeder.

I've opened up the feeder device, as much as can be done with fingers alone.  There just doesn't seem to be anything in there.  I ran a sheet of paper through about six times, just to see if some dust might be getting in the way, and I've blown out the feeder with air.   Still nothing.

At this point, I don't care too much about the ADF working, I just want to disable whatever sensor is tripping this error message.   Any ideas?

I found [this thread online](http://www.amazon.com/Canon-Pixma-MX340-Document-error/forum/Fx3UQ7SRAJBT29P/TxSZWFF4SWX89Q/1?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B0032AN4N0), where a user has the same problem.  But no resolution was reached there.

Answer (score 1):

If the bad sensor is preventing use of the printer, you probably have to get a warranty repair. It could also be a motherboard failure, which is extremely common on multifunctions in my experience. Attempting a firmware upgrade if one is available is the only thing I can think to try, once you've tried manual disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

For me it wasn't the ADF on the back, it was the one on the top. Lift up the top to show the photocopying glass. On the underside of the lid are two white tabs - give them both a gentle pull. On mine one had a little give and after that was fine. This was on an mx350 but imagine it'd be the same.

Answer (score -1):

So I had the same problem... I called technical support and they told me that parts are not even being made for my Pixel MX340 my only option was to upgrade... I asked if there's a way to disconnect the ADF and they said no that I probably had a bad sensor... so as determined as I am I figured if it's broken and I have nothing to loose by taking it apart and trying to fix it... so I took off both top pieces and pulled the wire for the ADF sensor...NOW I can still use my printer...

Comment: I’m having trouble determining whether you’re saying “I had the same problem...” or “I had the same problem, and here’s how I solved it.” If it’s the latter, please [edit] your post to clarify the solution and cut out the irrelevant narration.